# Running cdk synth ends batch script

Tags: .net, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a windows batch file which goes something like this:

```
dotnet lambda package

...

dotnet build

...

cdk synth
cdk deploy
```

The problem I'm having is that after `cdk synth` get executed the batch script simply stops processing and I have to manually run cdk deploy afterwards. Any idea why this would be happening?

I've noticed this happens with both cdk and cdklocal.

Comment: FYI, the `cdk deploy` command [synthesizes your app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-deploy-nosynth) by default, so as written the `cdk synth` command is redundant.